# Date parsing gone wrong

Tags: java, date, datetime

Working on an application which saves a date for a particular course i.e. the end date for every course that gets created.

This service accepts the date in MM/dd/yyyy format.

For example,

```
course = {
    "courseName": "My Course",
    "endDate": "01/10/2015"
}
```

Which should get parsed as "01/10/2015" i.e. "10 Jan 2015" in the service.

But, there were instances where the date was received in the wrong format, i.e dd/MM/yyyy

```
course = {
    "courseName": "My Course",
    "endDate": "13/01/2015"
}
```

Which got parsed as "01/01/2016" i.e. "01 Jan 2016".

The above parsing is done using

```
String d = "13/01/2015";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(d);
```

My question is, is there are way I can get back the original date by reversing the wrongly parsed date?

I tried to parsing it using pattern "dd/MM/yyyy", but I got "01/01/2016".

Comment: By reversing what? DateFormat can go both ways, but if you have parsed a date wrongly as 1 Jan, you're not going to be able to convert it to what it should have been unless you still have the original string that was parsed wrongly.

Comment: _"01/10/2015" i.e. "01 Jan 2015"_ do you mean 10 Jan 2015 or 01 Oct 2015 ?

Comment: "01/10/2015" i.e. "10 Jan 2015". My bad. I've edited the question.

Comment: @khelwood is right. If you don't have your string anymore you wont be able to get the original date back once converted. You need to detect first if the endDate is formated the right way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, once you have the parsed value "01/01/2016", how do you know whether that the original value was actually "01/01/2016" or your incorrect "13/01/2015". You don't.

All I can suggest is for future reference is that you [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) then the `SimpleDateFormat` will throw an appropriate `ParseException` when it encounters something like this.

```
String d = "13/01/2015";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
format.setLenient(false)
Date date = format.parse(d); // throws ParseException
```